# Flash AS3 Mobile App Button timeline control

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I know this is a very simple question, but its driving me nuts. I am trying to code a simple button in as3 to advance the main timeline to the nextframe. I am wanting to build a very simple app, and just want the buttons to go from one frame in the time line to the next. I think I have to use the touch event code, but I cant seem to figure out how to make it advance to the next frame. I have tried the old mouse event commands, but it dosent seem to work on my device when I test the app. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the way you described this, I am going to guess you are using the Flash Pro IDE and this is a timeline based application. If that is wrong, I apologize and I will try to update this answer.

It's really simple, actually. Just add code to your timeline (all code should be found on a single frame on a single layer, for what it is worth) that will listen for `MouseEvent.CLICK` on the button and move the timeline forward.

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClickHandler);

function btnClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this.nextFrame();
}
```

`btn` should be the reference name (see the Properties panel) of the button. `this` refers to the current top-level scope of your code. In this case, it is the main `MovieClip` object, which is what you refer to as the "main timeline".

[LiveDocs for `MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)

Comment: @user3173820 If this properly answered the question, please accept it by selecting the checkmark to the left of the answer. This will effectively close the question in the system  (and give the answerer rep in the process)